# Camel route loop not working

Tags: json, loops, apache-camel

I am trying to insert json data in mySQL database using camel and hibernate.
Everything is working.

```
for (Module module : modules) {
            from("timer://foo?delay=10000")
                    .loop(7)//not working
                    .to(module.getUrl() + "/api/json")
                    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                    .process(new Processor() {
                        @Override
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            int index = (Integer)exchange.getProperty("CamelLoopIndex"); // not working
                            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                            JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(exchange.getIn().getBody().toString());
                            String[] lijst = {"lastBuild", "lastCompletedBuild", "lastFailedBuild", "lastStableBuild", "lastSuccessfulBuild", "lastUnstableBuild", "lastUnsuccessfulBuild"};

                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

                            JsonNode node = root.get(lijst[index]);
                            JsonNode build = node.get("number");
                            obj.put("description", lijst[index]);
                            obj.put("buildNumber", build);

                            exchange.getIn().setBody(obj.toString());

                        }
                    })
                    .unmarshal(moduleDetail)
                    .to("hibernate:be.kdg.teamf.model.ModuleDetail")
                    .end();
        }
```

When I debug, my CamelLoopIndex remains 0 so it is not incremented every time it goes through the loop.

All help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In your case the only first instruction is processed in scope of the loop: `.to(module.getUrl() + "/api/json")`. You can add more instructions into a loop using Spring DSL, but I don't know how to declare a loop scope using Java DSL explicitly. I hope experts will explain more about a loop scope in Java DSL.

As a workaround I suggest to move all iteration instructions to a separate `direct:` route.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue as yours. It seems like a loop scope closes on the first to() instruction and it seems that the end() instruction does not makes sense. I didn't find anything about it in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. This works:

```
from("restlet:http://localhost:9010}/loop?restletMethod=get")
  .loop(7)
  .process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
      int index = (int) exchange.getProperty("CamelLoopIndex");
      exchange.getIn().setBody("index=" + index);
    }
  })
  .convertBodyTo(String.class)
  .end();
```

Output:

```
index=6
```